# How to select specific cells (from different rows or columns) from an excel file using VS 2010, C#, oledbconnection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

This is the code i'm using in my project:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\KursniListi.xlsx" + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
        (
            "SELECT *" +
            "FROM [Sheet1$]", conn
        );

        DataSet dsKL = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dsKL);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsKL.Tables[0];

    }
```

http://uploadpic.org/v.php?img=j8nn3BtVP2

I need this to display me: rows 1 and 11, columns C,E,F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide columns and rows on your datagrid using the Visible property

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
....

this.dataGridView1.Rows[1].Visible = false;
....
```

(I have used the index for the columns/rows because I can't type your header names)
However without knowing the requirement to hide rows it's difficult to give a satisfying answer.